# Почему не работает js в IE?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой в IE не хочет работать скрипт (начало через : NaN:NaN:NaN)

и еще как как добавить 0 к часам например нужно до 01:01:01 а выводит 1:1:1

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("2019-2-17T23:10:00+02:00").getTime();
//var countDownDate = new Date("2019, 2, 19, 23, 1, 0, GMT+03:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("conf_time").innerHTML = "начало через : " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("conf_time").innerHTML = "мероприятие уже проходит";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="conf_time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае используется какой-то странный формат даты. Вместо него нужно использовать стандартный формат ISO8601.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("2019-02-19T23:01:00+03:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("conf_time").innerHTML = "начало через : " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("conf_time").innerHTML = "мероприятие уже проходит";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="conf_time"></div>
```

Comment: а как добавить 0 к часам

Comment: @ПетроБойко, например так: `(n < 10? '0':'') + n`

Comment: + hours + Это сюда прописать

Comment: @ПетроБойко, это лучше в функцию вынести `var pad = n=>(n < 10? '0':'') + n`, и потом использовать как `pad(hours)` и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь